# How to split topics and contents into multiple rows?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a case with the underlying information. I would like to transpose the following which worked with the help of the WebAppStackExchange link, however, it doesn't split the names of the projects.

```
Project A | Jan, Feb, Mar 
Project B | Mar, Apr, Jun, Jul
Project C | Jan, Feb
```

I have been referring to this page and it helped a lot:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39822/split-content-of-one-row-into-multiple-rows

This is an example code from the StackExchange which worked for me.

```
=TRANSPOSE (SPLIT(REPT(CONCAT(B1; ","); COUNTA(B1:B3)); ","))
```

This is the ideal result:

```
Project A | Jan
Project A | Feb
Project A | Mar
Project B | Mar
Project B | Apr 
Project B | Jun
Project B | Jul
Project C | Jan
Project C | Feb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(LEN(A1:A), "♠"&A1:A&"♦"&IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B, ", ")), )),,999^99)),,999^99), 
 "♠")), "♦")), "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]